# Scripting on Android for game engine

Tags: java, android

I am making an android application, this is a game engine, almost everything is ready except for scripting.  How can you implement scripting on android?  So that the user can write all the logic of the game, the behavior of objects, etc.(as on Roblox for example)

I tried luaJ and luaJava, but it's very slow, with 1000 lines of code (the same camera shift method) fps drops to 20 on a PC, on a phone it's even worse.  On a PC, compiling and loading the script as a java class works perfectly, no fps drops!, But it works through the javax.tools and com.sun.tools libraries, when manually importing the classes of these libraries on the phone, it still does not want to work.  How is Rhino optimized?  Will it fit or are there other options?

Comment: This is way too vague a question for this site.  Also Rhino hasn't been an active project in most of a decade.  It was replaced by Nashorn, which itself is deprecated and no longer supported.